# Override HystrixCommandAspect bean in spring-cloud-netflix-hystrix

Tags: java, spring, aspectj, spring-cloud-netflix

The `HystrixCommandAspect` bean is declared in the `HystrixCircuitBreakerConfiguration` class but I would like to use my own custom implementation of `HystrixCommandAspect` and inject a different bean.

Application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@EnableCircuitBreaker
@Import(HystrixConfiguration.class)
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }
}
```

Configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class HystrixConfiguration {
    @Bean
    @Primary
    public HystrixCommandAspect hystrixCommandAspect(){
        return new com.hystrix.HystrixCommandAspect();
    }
}
```

Custom HystrixCommandAspect:

```
package com.hystrix;

@Aspect
public class HystrixCommandAspect extends com.netflix.hystrix.contrib.javanica.aop.aspectj.HystrixCommandAspect {
...
}
```

However, when I use the annotation `@EnableCircuitBreaker` it uses the `HystrixCircuitBreakerConfiguration` and doesn't even load my own `@Bean` definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded spring to the latest release and this fixed the problem. I also noticed in the logs that it said it was overriding the bean provided in `HystrixCircuitBreakerConfiguration`.